# File that hasn't been created

Tags: c, command-line

I am doing a c programming assignment where I am working with command-line arguments. One of the notes says that if the file you work with (to my understanding, it will always be "list.csv") is not yet created to create one. Just like vim does when you write "vim new.txt" and new.txt does not exist yet.

I am just wondering if there is a function that tests for the existence of a file? Or do I use some sort of try/catch block?

Comment: just open the file for writing. also, there is no such thing as `try` / `catch` blocks in C since the language doesn't have exceptions

Comment: so, fopen will create a file if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: its actually more interesting to know what happens if the file does exist,  do you overwrite it, or append on to the end of it ?

Comment: If the file exists, I just open it and read it with fopen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use fopen(). the second parameter says, what to do. Read, create+write, append+create(if not existent)

one way is to use fstat() on the filename.

under UNIX try 'man fstat'

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you want to write to a file the library or operating system API will automatically try to create it for you if it does not already exist. Exactly how you can control this depends on the API that you will be using.